# The Boolean ring $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$ has an ideal $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$. Find the elements of $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)/\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-ring

> Denote $\Bbb N_+ = \Bbb N \setminus\{0\}$. The Boolean ring $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$ has an ideal $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$. Find the elements of $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)/\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$ and compute the multiplication and addition tables.

Since this is asking me to compute the tables I feel like there should be a finite number of elements in $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)/\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$, but I have that $$\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)/\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)=\{A \triangle \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+) \mid A \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)\} = \{\{A  \triangle B \mid B \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)\} \mid A \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)\}$$ and for some reason this collection doesn't seem to be finite?

The sets $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N_+$ only differ by one element 0, but what about $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$ and $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$ it seems that the cardinality of $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$ so is the cardinality of $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$ equal to $2^{\aleph_0 -1}$ does the set $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)/\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$ contain only one element? I'm getting really confused here.

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that any element of $\mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ is congruent $\pmod {\mathscr P(\mathbb N_+)}$ to either $\emptyset$ or $\{0\}$?

Comment: $$\Large\textbf{Cardinals are not real numbers.}$$

Comment: @StinkingBishop How is congruence defined when I don't have addition or multiplication as my binary operations?

Comment: What do you mean "you don't have addition or multiplication"? Addition (and subtraction!) is $\Delta$ and multiplication is $\cap$. Two sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb N$ are equivalent/congruent (I've seen both words used!) if their difference is in $\mathscr P(\mathbb N_+)$ i.e. $A\Delta B\subseteq\mathbb N_+$.

Comment: So for $A \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$ and $B \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+)$ I have that $$A \triangle B = 0, \emptyset$$ always?

Comment: No. For every $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ *you can find $B\subseteq\mathbb N_+$* such that $A\Delta B=\emptyset$ or $A\Delta B=\{0\}$. Then, conclude from that that $\mathscr P(\mathbb N)/\mathscr P(\mathbb N_+)$ is a $2$-element set.

Comment: If this doesn't hold for every $A, B$ and I can only find such a $B$ for every $A$ why would that make the quotient ring a $2$-element set?

Comment: @RicoJello Check out the definition of the *quotient ring*.

Comment: If I take for example $\{0,1\} \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$, then $$\{0,1\} \triangle \mathscr{P}(\Bbb N_+) = \{, \dots, \{0,1\} \triangle K, \{0,1\} \triangle D, \dots \}$$ but I don't see what meaningful happens to these differences $\{0,1\} \triangle K, \{0,1\} \triangle D$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Prove that $\{A\triangle B:B\in P(\Bbb N_+)\}=P(\Bbb N_+)$ if $0\notin A$ and it's $=\{\{0\}\cup S:S\in P(\Bbb N_+)\}$ if $0\in A$.

Comment: If $A = \{0,1\}$ and say $B=\{3,4\}$, then $A \triangle B \ne \{0\} \cup B$ since $A \triangle B = \{0,1,3,4\}$, but $\{0\} \cup B = \{0,3,4\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I renamed the second occurrence of $B$. For that case of $A$ and $B$, you'll get $S=\{1,3,4\}$.